# QT5, QAbstractItemModel to QML getting strated

Tags: qml, qt5, qabstractitemmodel

iam a newbie in c++ sorry for may strange questions. 
I have a study task to do in QT and some problems getting Started:

I have to extract some data from a txt , put them in a database/model of QT and make them editable in a QML interface.

The data that i extract is for example (three examples):

Name: NAV.brake.radius

Value: 7
Description: Nav brake circle radius [m]

Name: NAV.slowdown.radius 
Value: 20

Description: Nav slowdown circle radius [m]

Name: CTRL.use.acc

Value: yes

Description: CTRL do use accelerometer

My main problem is: where should i store the data of the extraction ?

Should i store "Name" in a QString, Value in a QVAriant, Description in a QString , put them all in class "data" and data in some way into the AbstractItemModel? 
Or use the QStandardItemModel ?

I have realy problems to find an entry to the job. May some of you have a tips how to store or connect the data with the Modle ?

Best Wishes
ghali

Answer (score 0):

The AbstractItemModel provides you with an "Abstract" way of storing your data. There is no requirement at to your underlying data structure for maintaining data, other than that it is accessible via your implemented data(...) function call. Essentially, this implies your data should be visualized as some sort of index'ed container.

If I understand your question, you have a node with multiple data points. I would recommend modelling your node as a c++ struct and having your ItemModel implementation hold onto a map of index to this struct. From there, your data(...) function would be implemented to retrieve entries in this map by proper index.

Comment: Hey thank you that really helped ^^ ; i made a QMap with a customdata class where i store the extracted data from the .txt file. Have you another tipp how i put this QMap into a QStandardItemModel  ->
QStandardItem ?   Do subclassing the QStandartItem with my custom QMap? - thx ! ^_^

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting what it means for data to be part of a model. There is no need to have it subclass any sort of QStandardItem, you simply need to give your model the proper way to access data from your QMap by reimplementing the data(...) method in the model.